# Memory and CPU problems clicking back button - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, out-of-memory, cpu

My app has a memory\CPU's problem: when I press my back button in a specific page the memory and CPU grow up and grow up and so the app crashes.

[image: Statistics]

I use a scrollview with about 40 buttons with special properties and constraints. Each button has a function. There are also many views which form a grid on my page.
I have this problem only when I press my back button in this specific page.

Probably the page is too big? I have also used this function to dismiss the page without effect:

```
    func back(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    // Go back to the previous ViewController
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

This is my function to change UILabel background color when I press a button:

```
func changeColor(sender: ElectroButton){

    let args = arrayFunc
    weak var label1, label2, label3, label4: ElectroLabel!

    for arg in args {
        if arg.objectType == "LBL" && arg.variableName == sender.variableName{
            print(arg.variableName, sender.variableName)
            let label = arg as! ElectroLabel
            label.redColor = sender.redColor
            label.blueColor = sender.blueColor
            label.greenColor = sender.greenColor
            label.backgroundColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: label.redColor, green: label.greenColor, blue: label.blueColor, alpha: 1)
            label.actualValue = sender.actualValue
        }

        if arg.objectType == "LBL"{
            switch arg.variableName! {
            case "LBL1":
                label1 = arg as! ElectroLabel
            case "LBL2":
                label2 = arg as! ElectroLabel
            case "LBL3":
                label3 = arg as! ElectroLabel
            case "LBL4":
                label4 = arg as! ElectroLabel
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }

    for arg in args {

        if arg.objectType == "LBL" && arg.variableName == "RRISULTANTE"{
            let label = arg as! ElectroLabel
            let firstCh = label.variableSymbol.characters.first
            for el in sender.dictOfMeasure{
                if "\(firstCh!)" == el.value{
                    let index = label.variableSymbol.index((label.variableSymbol.startIndex), offsetBy: 1)
                    label.variableSymbol = label.variableSymbol.substring(from: index)
                    break
                }
            }
            label.actualKey = "4"

            let result = ((label1.actualValue! + label2.actualValue!) as NSString).floatValue * (label3.actualValue! as NSString).floatValue
            label.actualValue = String(result)

            self.changeSymbOp3(sender: label)

            label.text = label.actualValue + " " + label.variableSymbol + " " + label4.actualValue + " %"

        }

    }



}
```

This is my func to position my objects in the page:

```
func detectElementPosition(arrayPos: Array<String>, object: AnyObject){


    var a = 0
    var b = 0

    while a < 121 {

        let row: UIView? = {
            let row = UIView()
            row.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            scrollView.addSubview(row)
            return row
        }()

        row.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: section_width).isActive = true
        row.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0).isActive = true
        row.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor, constant: box_height*CGFloat(a)).isActive = true



        if a == Int(arrayPos[2]) {
            object.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: row.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        }

        if a == Int(arrayPos[3]) {
            object.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: row.topAnchor).isActive = true
        }


        a+=1
    }

    while b < 51 {

        let line: UIView = {
            let section = UIView()
            section.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            //section.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
            return section
        }()
        scrollView.addSubview(line)
        line.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: section_height).isActive = true
        line.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0).isActive = true
        line.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leftAnchor, constant: box_width*CGFloat(b)).isActive = true

        if b == Int(arrayPos[4]) {
            object.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: line.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        }

        if b == Int(arrayPos[5]) {
            object.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: line.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        }

        b+=1

    }



}
```

This is my output:

```
Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You say the application crashes? Do you have a stack trace? You should post that if you have it. The amount of information you supplied is not quite enough to determine the actual problem. Additionally, it's better to show the problem than describe the problem, since your description may not be as telling as the raw information itself.

Comment: I have integrated my question